# Mysql_query UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

I could swear that I had this working last week, but now I get errors.

In PHP I have a large CSV file that I run through a foreach loop and in this loop I have a created a variable that adds an UPDATE line to itself, like this:

```
foreach ($csv->data as $value){
   $updater .= "UPDATE tblProduktData SET xtra = 2 WHERE id = '$value[1]';";
}
mysql_query("$updater") or die(mysql_error());
```

The CSV file contains over 3000 lines so having the mysql_query() inside the loop obviously makes the process slow and is not recommendable.

Can anyone tell me if I'm missing something or just doing it wrong?

Comment: you're trying to run multiple queries in a single query() call. this is not permitted for security reasons.

Comment: What is your error message?

Comment: Switch to a API that is not **deprecated** which has prepared statements, and then use prepared statements for this.

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 1):

> We will temporarily ignore the fact that you are using a PHP extension *mysql_* that has been deprecated ( Scheduled for removal from the language) for a number of years now.

For some reason you are adding to the sql query each time through the loop by using the `.=` syntax. I assume you thought you could run more than one query at a time using the mysql_ extension, but you cannot.

So try this :-

```
foreach ($csv->data as $value){
   $updater = "UPDATE tblProduktData SET xtra = 2 WHERE id = '$value[1]'";
   mysql_query($updater) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

This is in fact a perfect candidate for using mysqli_ or PDO prepared statements.

[The mysqli_ extension manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

[The PDO manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly - I think the easiest for me to understand would be mysqli, so I will try to "convert" to this. What you are saying is that no matter the PHP extension I will not be able to perform only one query that updates the 3000+ rows? I will have to, just like the above example from you, to perform a mysqli_query for every row in the CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$id = "0"; // initialze the ids to update with a non-existing value
// fetch all the ids into a variable
foreach ($csv->data as $value){
  $id .= "," . $value[1] 
}

$updater .= "UPDATE tblProduktData SET xtra = 2 WHERE id in (".$id.") ;";
mysql_query("$updater") or die(mysql_error());
```